# My Index page has very lots of white space after the footer need to remove that?

Tags: html, footer

Just started working on a PSD to HTML and got to this stage that i completed all the things fine,as i know it's a start so i did bad CSS programming but slowly slowly will learn if you people help me so i will get succeed.so here is the index file please check must that why there is alot of white space after the footer,and how to remove that white space?

the index file : http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/urgent_psd/index.html

waiting for your replies..

Comment: Do you have any code to work with?

Comment: pardon please i didn't understand?

Comment: Can you share the code?? Fiddle or something?

Comment: Sure.here is the index.html code : http://pastebin.com/sKTWvxQN

Comment: and here is the style.css code : http://pastebin.com/06ryQzNh

Comment: possible duplicate of [too much white space in the last of content div and before footer need that to be removed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267395/too-much-white-space-in-the-last-of-content-div-and-before-footer-need-that-to-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#footer {
background-image: url(../images/footer_back.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top: 1250px;// Remove this
padding: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
```

In your style.css file remove top:1250px inside #footer

Even if you dont remove this, you can change the value to something to your requirement, probably less than 100px

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    background-image:url(../images/footer_back.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100px;
    background-position:center top;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:1250px;
    padding: 100px;
    margin:0;
}
```

As I see in your code, you are using a lot of padding in all the four sides (therefore, including bottom). Try this instead: padding: 100px 100px 100px 0; and perhaps: background-position:center bottom;

Comment: edited and added : padding: 100px 100px 100px 0; and background-position:center bottom; so please check back the link for new look.still showing wrong.

Comment: Oh, well, I see that you fixed it already by removing the padding. I'm sorry if I gave you swapped parameters in the padding, I often do mistake with them.