# too much white space in the last of content div and before footer need that to be removed?

Tags: html, footer

Hope you all will be fine..!

I just started converting a PSD to HTML as i am beginner learner so did bad HTML/CSS programming,so here i am facing an issue now,that has alot of white space right in the last of content and before footer which need to be removed.

here is the link to the Index.html page : http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/urgent_psd/index.html

waiting for you people replies..

Comment: very bad...no one give me any voting but positive voting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your CSS**

```
  #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/footer_back.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; 
    top: 1250px;   //  this is causing the white space..!!
    padding: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
    }
```

remove this `top: 1250px;`

and add `bottom:0;` for the footer

**Try**

```
  #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/footer_back.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom:0; 
    padding: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
    }
```

or you could also give `top:50px`// a reasonable space

**Try**

```
 #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/footer_back.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ok you have placed top:1250px, which is very high, so you should make it around 20-30px.

So check your style.css file and find the below code :

```
 #footer {
 background-image: url(../images/footer_back.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: bottom;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 top: 1250px; /* cahnge here - make it 20px */
 padding: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
 }
```

So find the above block at style.css file and do change as mention above.

Comment: thanks..for reply bro..I just checked it myself..and find out the top and removed that..and that worked...as i needed that so fast..that's why..although it was my first site which I converted From PSD to HTML..

Answer (score 0):

You have stated `top: 1250px;` to the footer, that's why it's going down.

Remove the top in here:

```
#footer {
    background-image: url("../images/footer_back.png");
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 150px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1250px;
}
```

Like this:

```
#footer {
    background-image: url("../images/footer_back.png");
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply..Yeah..I just checked myself and removed the top from css.and worked..

Comment: Mark it as answered than.

Answer (score 0):

Footer div is absolutely positioned 1250px down and has a top padding of 150px.

Reduce/remove these and you should be happy. Define padding with more than one value, when two values the first one is top/bottom, second is left and right. Try

```
padding: 20px 150px;
```

or adjust to taste.

P.S. This site is probably not going to look very good on tablets/mobiles - I suggest you try and get the site to look good on small displays and read articles on responsive design...

Comment: thanks...vogomatix..you sure..give good suggestions thanks..any how where i can find the best responsive design tutorials?